# How to bind a function to the Windows key

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

I want to bind the function `evil-normal-state` to the windows key on my keyboard. How do I do that? Also is there a way to bind the `Fn` key to other functions?

I am using Emacs 26.1 on a Linux-Mint system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, the `Windows` key is intercepted by the desktop manager, so Emacs doesn't see it.  As for the `Fn` key, `C-h c` says that Emacs sees this key as `<XF86WakeUp>`; so, for example, I could bind it to `execute-extended-command` with:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<XF86WakeUp>") 'execute-extended-command)
```